# TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance with useContext in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

LOG  [TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a Symbol.iterator method.]

With my UserContext :

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { UserType } from "../UserContext";

const [userId, setUserId] = useContext(UserType);

const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("authToken");
            const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
            const userId = decodedToken.userId;
            console.log(userId);
            setUserId(userId);
```

this is my UserContext.js

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

const UserType = createContext();

const UserContext = ({ children }) => {
    const { userId, setUserId } = useState("");
    return (
        <UserType.Provider value={{ userId, setUserId }}>
            {children}
        </UserType.Provider>
    )
}

export {UserType, UserContext}
```

My App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import StackNavigator from './StackNavigator'
import { UserContext } from './UserContext';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <UserContext>
    <StackNavigator/>
    </UserContext>
    </>
  );
}
```

please if someone can help me

i have tried to change

```
const [userId, setUserId] = useContext(UserType);
```

with

```
const {userId, setUserId} = useContext(UserType);
```

but it give me this error

```
TypeError: setUserId is not a function (it is undefined)
```

Comment: You're trying to destructure an object as if it was an array (which fails entirely because objects aren't all iterable). Then once you've fixed that you're elsewhere trying to destructure an array as if it was an object (which succeeds, because arrays _are_ objects, but with undefined property values).

Comment: The error may exist since the default UserType is not defined before it is read. Try declaring the default values of variables you are using in UserContext.js

`
const UserType = createContext({
userId: null,
setUserId: () => {}
});
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you used this `useContext` in the wrong way. Whatever you pass through the provider, you will get that same object as a response through the `useContext`.

So here, you `useContext` hook will be ([Doc For Help](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext))

```
const { userId, setUserId } = useContext(UserType);
```

But you will get an error as `setUserId is not a function but undefined`. Because you made another mistake inside the **UserContext.js** file. You have written the `useState` hook as ([Doc For Help](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState))

```
const { userId, setUserId } = useState("");
```

but `useState` **always returns an array of two values** like - `[value, setValue]`, not an **object**. So, it should be

```
const [ userId, setUserId ] = useState("");
```

I think it will solve your issue. I have also shared the related docs link for better understanding.